# tcp stream NGINX performance issue

Tags: centos7, iptables, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to setup a proxy between by application server and public world, i have tried NGINX but facing lot of issues like connection drop, FIN-WAITS, CONNECTION-WAITS etc

I have enabled stream model in NGINX and have config as mentioned below, also have opened all required ports on Centos 7 using iptables my selinux is off

```
{ ## In /etc/nginx/conf.d/stream/stream.conf
server {
        listen 6775 reuseport;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_timeout 1m;
        proxy_pass my.appserver.com:6775;
   }
```

If by changing any config i can improve Ngixn performance or should i try HAProxy
As I need to restart Nginx often as client complaint of connect lost or reconnecting
I had followed the document "http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html"